# Using Vicinity x iBeacons to Broadcast and Receive Unique Identifier from the BG

Tags: ios, uuid, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon

A few years ago I had the idea for something the resembles Apples iBeacons that would allow my app to scan and receive from the bg to find other devices for a project im working on. When I heard about iBeacons I got excited , but it was short lived when I heard about its limitations and then I came across this project on Github:https://github.com/Instrument/Vicinity

Which we were able to get to broadcast and receive at the same time , but were having issues getting any kind of unique identifier when the phone is asleep, yet it continues to pick up the beacons of other devices using our UUID and it finds more than 1 device even from the bg so there has to be a unique identifier somewhere right?

If not is there a way for us to parse the packet ourselves and find some unique identifier?

Answer (score 0):

iBeacons have special system support. They use a UUID independent of the normal peripheral UUID for BLE services.

The Location Manager listens for the beacons you've asked to monitor even when your app is in the background, and even when your app has been terminated due to memory pressure. If it detects a beacon state change that you've asked to be notified of, it will re-launch your app if necessary, and send you a notification in the background. You have a few seconds to do something about it before your app goes back to sleep.

You can't send beacon signals from the background using the system iBeacon support. I **THINK** it's possible to transmit BLE advertisements from the background if you've set the correct background flags in your info.plist and made the right calls to set it up, but I haven't tried it myself, at least not yet.